# Laravel: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long

Tags: php, laravel

Fui fazer a criação das tabelas no banco de dados, mas me mostra o erro: `Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`.

Como arrumar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece pois o *Laravel* alterou o valor *default* dos campos. Para corrigir isso, basta ir no arquivo `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` e adicionar o seguinte código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Na realidade você está alterando o valor default executando esse comando, o erro realmente ocorre pelo fato de o banco não estar com o encode correto, no seu arquivo database.php você pode alterar o `charset` e o `collation` e irá funcionar, ai não precisa mexer no padrão de String.
`'charset' => 'utf8mb4',`
`'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',`
`'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',`

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma de resolver é adicionar o nome do índice no segundo parâmetro:

```
$table->string('seu_campo')->unique(null,'chave');
```